# Show Product Name in 3 Tables in Laravel Relationship Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Can you help me again? I have 3 tables

```
Product Table
id
product_name


Productquantity Table
id
item_id
price

Orders
id
req_id
quantity_id
quantity
amount
```

How can I get the product name in my CartView? I only have this in my code

Reqorder Model

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTO('App\Productquantity', 'item_id', 'id');
    }
```

My Controller

```
 $dataReqorder = Reqorder::where('req_id','=', $shoppingId)->with('product')->get();
```

My View

```
@foreach($dataReqorder as $order)
<tr class="item{{$order->id}}">
<td> <a href="products/{{$order->id}}" class="name">{{$order->product->prod_id}}</a> </td>
<td>{{$order->amount}}</td>
<td>{{$order->quantity}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I want this {{$order->product->prod_id}} should be the name of the product instead of the product ID.. I just do not know how to do it on model and controller.. Please help

How can I create my controller, model and view in order for me to display the product name?